# URL Rewrite - Remove End of URL If Matches Specific String

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Using URL rewrite and we have lots of old URLs which take the form

```
/something/else/index.cfm
/this/that/index.cfm
```

What I would like to do is remove the `/index.cfm` from these examples

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="Remove Trailing Index.cfm" enabled="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/index.cfm" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="category" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```